# XSL/HTML number of table row adjustment

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I'm currently using XML v1.0. I am running into an issue where I can't create a new row for each of my "Dog"s. I attached a screenshot to help visualize what I have and the outcome. The first screenshot is what I have. The second screenshot points to what I'm trying to fix. Each of the "Dog" should be in it's own box.

[image]
[image]

What I'm trying to do is have long list of "Dog" to be in it's own table space. The current code I have is something like this:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="animal-list/list">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="cat-list"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="dog-list">
                        <apply-templates select="dog">
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                            <br/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I have tried replacing the `<br/>` with various different tags to try and achieve my goal. But nothing I tried worked. So to clarify my question is, how can I have the "Dog" in their own little table data/row, as in having lines between each "Dog"

Edit:

Here is the XML data:

```
                <animal-list>
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list>
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list> 
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list>
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list>
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list>
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list>
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list>
                    <list>
                        <cat-list>Cat</cat-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                        <dog-list>Dog</dog-list>
                    </list>
                </animal-list>
```

Comment: You should show your input XML and specify which dogs are to be associated with which cats.

Comment: For this, I'm not actually too worried about what the data is. I'm just stuck basically on what would make the table actually display correctly, regardless of what the data says, dog, cat, monkey, etc. What I'm saying is, `<tr/>` or `<td/>` doesn't work when replacing it with `<br/>`, what other method could achieve the result.

Comment: You may not be worried, but the question is not quite clear without it. It's also difficult to test an answer without some data - so why don't you just provide it instead of expecting others to do it for you?

Comment: how actually it shold looks like if you got more then two cats in list?

Comment: There's never more than one cat per list. But there can be multiple dogs for each cat. The final result will actually have multiple columns after dogs, that's why I'm looking into how to create a separate group for each of them.

Comment: I think you need to clarify if the one cat in the last list needs to be associated with the many dogs in the same list (i.e span that many rows), or are the columns independent of each other. The other thing is that an HTML table is built row-by-row - so if you have more columns to include, they need to be included here and now, not later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's some weird input, I'll say. Anyhow, here's one way to look at it. This is assuming the cat and dogs columns are independent of each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Cats</th>
        <th>Dogs</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:call-template name="createRows">
        <xsl:with-param name="cats" select="animal-list/list/cat-list"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="dogs" select="animal-list/list/dog-list"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="createRows">
    <xsl:param name="cats"/>
    <xsl:param name="dogs"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>

    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= count($cats) or $i &lt;= count($dogs)">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$cats[$i]"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$dogs[$i]"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="createRows">
            <xsl:with-param name="cats" select="$cats"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="dogs" select="$dogs"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In case the above assumption is wrong:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Cats</th>
        <th>Dogs</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="animal-list/list">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="count(dog-list) > 1">
                    <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(dog-list)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="cat-list"/>
            </td>   
            <td><xsl:value-of select="dog-list[1]"/></td>
        </tr>           
        <xsl:for-each select="dog-list[position() > 1]">
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This way dog-list trs (those with position > 1) will be inside first tr. You have to put them outside.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

No XML means no XSLT, so I guess you have an HTML problem more than an XSLT one. You must use `rowspan` attribute, for example:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">cat</td>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to do that with XSLT is another question which can't be answered without XML.

**Updated**:
You can try with this xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" />

<!-- template for root element: table element and apply-templates for cat-list elements -->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="animal-list/list/cat-list"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for cat-list elements -->
<xsl:template match="cat-list">
  <!-- count all dog-list elements which are 'children of my parent node' -->
  <xsl:variable name="mysiblings" select="parent::list/dog-list" /><!-- this variable will contain all of mi dog-list siblings -->
  <xsl:variable name="myspan" select="count($mysiblings)" /><!-- this variable will contain the number of them -->

  <!-- for every cat-list: one row -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="{$myspan}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- output my text -->
    </td>
    <!-- first dog-list: inside same tr -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$mysiblings[1]" />
  </tr>
  <!-- rest of them outside: they have their own tr: -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$mysiblings[position() &gt; 1]" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for dog-list elements, general -->
<xsl:template match="dog-list">
  <!-- tr and td  -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- output my text -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for the first one. This one will go inside same tr as the cat -->
<xsl:template match="dog-list[position() = 1]">
  <!-- just td  -->
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- output my text -->
  </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Didn't know the XML data is actually that important. So I created something that is similar to what the xml data I have is, since I'm actually unable to share the actual content. Hopefully this creates less confusion. Thanks for the help. XML added to original post.